# Using structure as buffer holder

Tags: c++, c, opencl

In my current OpenCL implementation, I wanted to save time with arguments, avoid to pass them every time I wanted to use a buffer inside a kernel and have a shorter argument list for my kernel.

So I made a structure (workspace) that holds the pointer to the buffer in device memory, the struct act like an object with member variable you want to access through time and you want to stay alive for the whole execution. I never had a problem on AMD GPU or even on CPU. But Nvidia causing a lot of problems with this. It always seems to be an alignment problem, never reaching to right buffer, etc.

Here some code to help, see question below:

The structure define on host:

```
 #define SRC_IMG 0       // (float4 buffer) Source image
 #define LAB_IMG 1       // (float4 buffer) LAB image

 // NOTE: The size of this array should be as much as the last define + 1.
 #define __WRKSPC_SIZE__ 2 

 // Structure defined on host.
 struct Workspace
 {
      cl_ulong getPtr[__WRKSPC_SIZE__];
 };

 struct HostWorkspace
 {
      cl::Buffer srcImg;
      cl::Buffer labImg;
 };
```

The structure defined on device:

```
typedef struct __attribute__(( packed )) gpuWorkspace
{
    ulong getPtr[__WRKSPC_SIZE__]; 
} gpuWorkspace_t;
```

Note that on device, I use ulong and on host I use cl_ulong as shown here [OpenCL: using struct as kernel argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33119233/opencl-using-struct-as-kernel-argument).

So once cl::Buffer for source image or LAB image are created, I save them into a HostWorkspace object, so until that object is released, the reference to cl::Buffer is kept, so buffer exists for the entire project on the host, and defacto on the device.

Now, I need to feed those the device, so I have a simple kernel which init my device workspace as follow:

```
__kernel void Workspace_Init(__global gpuWorkspace_t* wrkspc,
                             __global float4* src,
                             __global float4* LAB)
{
    // Get the ulong pointer on the first element of each buffer.
    wrkspc->getPtr[SRC_IMG] = &src[0];
    wrkspc->getPtr[LAB_IMG] = &LAB[0];
}
```

where wrkspc is a buffer allocated with `struct Workspace`, and src + LAB are just buffer allocate as 1D array images.

And afterwards, in any of my kernel, if I want to use src or LAB, I do as follow:

```
__kernel void ComputeLABFromSrc(__global gpuWorkspace_t* wrkSpc)
{
    // =============================================================
    // Get pointer from work space.
    // =============================================================

    // Cast back the pointer of first element as a normal buffer you
    // want to use along the execution of the kernel.
    __global float4* srcData = ( __global float4* )( wrkSpc->getPtr[SRC_IMG] );
    __global float4* labData = ( __global float4* )( wrkSpc->getPtr[LAB_IMG] );

    // Code kernel as usual.
}
```

When I started to use this, I had like 4-5 images which was going well, with a different structure like this:

```
struct Workspace
{
    cl_ulong imgPtr;
    cl_ulong labPtr;
};
```

where each image had there own pointer.

At a certain point I reach more images, and I had some problem. So I search online, and I found some recommendation that the sizeof() the struct could be different in-between device/host, so I change it to a single array of the same time, and this works fine until 16 elements.

So I search more, and I found a recommendation about the **attribute**((packed)), which I put on the device structure (see above). But now, I reach 26 elements, when I check the sizeof the struct either on device or on host, the size is 208 (elements * sizeof(cl_ulong) == 26 * 8). But I still have a similar issue to my previous model, my pointer goes read somewhere else in the middle of the previous image, etc.

So I have wondering, if anyone ever try a similar model (maybe with a different approach) or have any tips to have a "solid" model with this.

Note that all kernel are well coded, I have a good result when executing on AMD or on CPU with the same code. The only issue is on Nvidia.

Comment: Which language, C or C++?  They are distinct languages.  C++ has `std::vector` and `std::array` as well as pass by reference.  The C language doesn't have these items.

Comment: OpenCL is C, so all my device code is in C. But the host code (which I didn't provide that much) use C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't try to store GPU-side pointer values across kernel boundaries. They are not guaranteed to stay the same. Always use indices. And if a kernel uses a specific buffer, you need to pass it as an argument to that kernel.

References:

1. The OpenCL 1.2 specification (as far as I'm aware, nvidia does not implement a newer standard) does not define the behaviour of pointer-to-integer casts or vice versa.
2. Section 6.9p states: **"Arguments to kernel functions that are declared to be a struct or union do not allow OpenCL objects to be passed as elements of the struct or union."** This is exactly what you are attempting to do: passing a struct of buffers to a kernel.
3. Section 6.9a states: **"Arguments to kernel functions in a program cannot be declared as a pointer to a pointer(s)."** - This is essentially what you're trying to subvert by casting your pointers to an integer and back. (point 1) You can't "trick" OpenCL into this being well-defined by bypassing the type system.

As I suggest in the comment thread below, you will need to use indices to save positions inside a buffer object. If you want to store positions across different memory regions, you'll need to either unify multiple buffers into one and save one index into this giant buffer, or save a numeric value that identifies which buffer you are referring to.

Comment: Could you be more specific about `Always use indices` ? I dont understand.

Comment: @Vuwox If you need to save a position in a buffer from one kernel invocation to another, you need to use an integer array index, not a pointer.

Comment: OpenCL doesn't allow to have pointer in structure. So I already store "index" in your term. You do you mean I should do : `wrkspc->getPtr[SRC_IMG] = src[0];` instead of `&src[0]` ? Because that will only store the value contain at position 0 imo. I don't get it.

Comment: OpenCL does allow pointers in structures, you just mustn't use them to pass pointers in and out of kernels, *because pointers are only valid within that one kernel invocation, and are not the same on host vs device*. Whether you do this with a pointer-typed field or by casting a pointer to an integer type (which is what you're trying to do) doesn't matter, it's still not valid.

Comment: (The fact that you're having to cast from a pointer type to an integer type should already be telling you that what you're trying to do is a bad idea and is not going to work.)

Comment: @Vuwox `&src[0]` is a virtual memory address on the CPU side. You are storing that pointer as a `ulong`. You then try to access that pointer from the GPU side, which 1) most likely has a different virtual address space and 2) likely operates on completely different physical memory. Both of these (individually already) mean your CPU-side pointer points to garbage on the GPU side.

Comment: @MaxLanghof I believe it's all on the GPU side: @Vuwox appears to first enqueue the `Workspace_Init` kernel to "initialise" his struct-of-pointers, then attempt to use those pointers in the `ComputeLABFromSrc` kernel. But although both are on the device, it's still not well-defined.

Comment: @pmdj Right, my apologies.

Comment: Yes, everything is on device. This might be not well-defined, Im just wondering why my AMD works perfectly with this, and Nvidia works also for a certain time and start to have issue after a while. Like my pipeline have 26 buffer currently, when accessing the 25 first, there is no issue, but when trying to access the 26 at kernel execution 67, it start to do weird thing. So I just wanted to get explaination why is not working and is there any other solution, except passing them as argument every time. I might have to do it, Im just searching for another approach.

Comment: If any of you, have reference or something I could read about the fact "they are not guaranteed to stay the same.". I would appreciate, Im just a curious developer, I made that from scratch and its my first OpenCL project. Im here to learn.

Comment: Like any undefined behaviour, it might behave as you intended some of the time, but not always. The answer remains the same: don't try to rely on undefined behaviour. Yes, you will need to pass buffers as kernel arguments. You can make this a little easier for yourself by using one large buffer object instead of many small ones, and saving indices into this one large buffer.

Comment: @Vuwox I've provided some references in my answer now. Those are probably as good as you're going to get - basically, the standard doesn't specify how what you're trying to do will behave, so it's undefined. For the most part, the standard doesn't enumerate all the things you *aren't* allowed to rely on, just the ones that you are.

Comment: Thanks. I already tried the idea of a large single buffer before. But this is too hard to maintain due to device buffer limit (1/4th of the memory usually). I think, I will have to set arguments one-by-one despite sometime this can be terrible (over 15 arguments). Thanks again.

Comment: Just to let you know why I tried that approach, is because I found this in the past https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14330291/base-address-of-memory-object-opencl. But I re-read that carefully, and I understand now, the second answer is the good one. Like you said, I should prefer indices to pointer.

Comment: And here another articles I just found with the same problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36246239/copying-global-on-device-pointer-address-back-and-forth-between-device-and-host, this lead me to conclusion that device address is okay inside the same kernel, but not guaranteed to be the same in time.